# Uninstall snap but not snap-installed apps?

Tags: 20.04, snap

There is one app that I need which is only available as a snap and nothing else.

I had removed snap from my system, preferring flatpak instead, but now I need to re-setup snap for this app.

I'm wondering if I can remove snap without uninstalling the apps? I tried it and it uninstalled the app itself.

If this isn't possible, then why is that? Isn't a package manager just supposed to put the binaries and scripts in the right place on your system ?

Comment: I see. I've updated the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snapd is more than a package manager.

- It loop-mounts the snap application at startup.
- It has a role in the sandboxing: The AppArmor rules, access controls, and $PATH redirection. It monitors the connections among snaps and the system.